# HIbernate Group by and Order By not working when used at the same time?

Tags: java, hibernate

when i try to group and order by at the same time with hibernate, it just group by, order by seems to be ignored. Why is that so, how i can use them togehter?

```
list = session.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Student a GROUP BY a.firstname ORDER BY (a.date) DESC ", Student.class).getResultList();
```

Comment: Your query looks meaningless, what do you actually want to have as result? See for examples [this part](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-group-by) of hibernate documentation.

Comment: why meaningless? If we assume that there are Students with the same firstname, i want only to show each name once. This ordered in DESC order, because i do not want to group by students with an old date

Comment: Select those two columns only. Otherwise, it can't group for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA specification imposes the following restriction on the `group by` clause (see section *4.7 GROUP BY, HAVING*):

> ... The requirements for the `SELECT` clause when `GROUP BY` is used follow those of SQL: namely, *any item that appears in the `SELECT` clause (other than as an aggregate function or as an argument to an aggregate function) must also appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.* In forming the groups, null values are treated as the same for grouping purposes.
>
> Grouping by an entity is permitted. In this case, the entity must contain no serialized state fields or lob-valued state fields that are eagerly fetched. Grouping by an entity that contains serialized state fields or lob-valued state fields is not portable, since the implementation is permitted to eagerly fetch fields or properties that have been specified as LAZY.
>
> Grouping by embeddables is not supported. ...

So, taken this in mind, the correct query may look like this:

```java
List<Object[]> result = session.createQuery(
    "select a.firstname, max(a.date) as max_date " +
    "from Student a " +
    "group by a.firstname " +
    "order by max_date", Object[].class )
.getResultList();
```

Comment: With Object[] i get any result, with Student i get this error : **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type**

Comment: You should use `Object[]` or some projection class here. See [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-clause)